# PyQt - Use SQL directly with QSqlTableModel

Tags: sql, database, qt, pyqt

I'm writing a simple student scores manager for practicing programming on PyQt (I don't want to use terrible *Visual Basic* anymore). But I had a big problem on choose data models.

I found `QSqlTableModel` first, it is a great model with auto-updating. The trouble is, I need to use a lot of SQL (`JOIN`, `WHERE`) to select data from database. `QSqlTableModel` has `select()` and `filter()` only.

Then I found `QSqlQueryModel`, but it is read only. So I rewrite its  `setData()` method. So it is read-write now. Unfortunately, `QSqlQueryModel` less usable features than `QSqlTableModel`.

As you see, if I can using SQL with `QSqlTableModel`, I can resolve all my problems.

So...?

Answer (score 1):

`QSqlTableModel` has the `setQuery` method, which you can use to set a custom query, something like:

```
model = QSqlTableModel()
query = QSqlQuery(your_query)
model.setQuery(query)
```

However, the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqltablemodel.html#setQuery) states:

> This function simply calls QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query). You should normally not call it on a QSqlTableModel. Instead, use setTable(), setSort(), setFilter(), etc., to set up the query.

Comment: I think `setFilter()` is what you are looking for

Comment: The same cited documentation gives examples of simple tables that unnecessarily use `setQuery()`. So the documentation is a bit schizofrenic about this subject :-)